# polymer iron-ajax body received in express extra object

Tags: json, express, polymer-1.0

I am trying to send a JSON object from my polymer application to my express API.

I do the following on the client:

```
<iron-ajax
    id="createRoomAjax"
    url="{{url}}{{roomRoute}}"
    handle-as="json"
    method="POST"
    on-response="onRoomCreated"
    debounce-duration="300">
</iron-ajax>

createRoom: function() {
  this.$.createRoomAjax.body = {
    'name': roomname.value
  };
  this.$.createRoomAjax.generateRequest();
  // console.log(this.$.createRoomAjax);
},
```

On the express side I print the following:

```
function(req, res, next) {
   console.log(req.body);
}
```

Which gives me the following output:

> { 
>       '{"name":"jljk"}': ''  }

I would expect that in my express app I would receive a req with a body: {name: '...'} instead of an extra object that surrounds it. Could someone explain to me why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the solution to my problem. It seems that I need to set the contentType of my iron-ajax request to json otherwise it sends the body-payload differently.

new HTML:

```
  <iron-ajax
        id="createRoomAjax"
        url="{{url}}{{roomRoute}}"
        method="POST"
        content-type="application/json"
        on-response="onRoomCreated"
        debounce-duration="300">
    </iron-ajax>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try using `params` instead of `body` like so:

```
  this.$.createRoomAjax.params = {
    'name': roomname.value
}
```

This works well for me using Polymer and Express.

Comment: thank you for your answer but I would like to send it in the body!